# IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical when creating a GridSpringBean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gridgain

So I'm using Spring 4 + Spring Boot + Gridgain 6.0.1 to create a web app and I wanted to run the app as an executable jar, but then I ran into an issue of java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical. I did some research and looks like this is a general issue when running an executable jar (run fine in IDE and as an executable file, i.e. a .tar file generated by gradle 'application' plugin). I'm wondering is this a bug in GridGain? Here is part of the stacktrace:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
at java.io.File.(File.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0]
at org.gridgain.grid.util.GridUtils.resolveProjectHome(GridUtils.java:2250) ~[gridgain-platform-6.0.1.jar!/:na]
at org.gridgain.grid.util.GridUtils.getGridGainHome(GridUtils.java:2291) ~[gridgain-platform-6.0.1.jar!/:na]
at org.gridgain.grid.GridGain$GridNamedInstance.start0(GridGain.java:1326) ~[gridgain-platform-6.0.1.jar!/:na]
at org.gridgain.grid.GridGain$GridNamedInstance.start(GridGain.java:1291) ~[gridgain-platform-6.0.1.jar!/:na]
at org.gridgain.grid.GridGain.start0(GridGain.java:850) ~[gridgain-platform-6.0.1.jar!/:na]
at org.gridgain.grid.GridGain.start(GridGain.java:530) ~[gridgain-platform-6.0.1.jar!/:na]
at org.gridgain.grid.GridSpringBean.afterPropertiesSet(GridSpringBean.java:127) ~[gridgain-platform-6.0.1.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.5.RELEASE]
... 21 common frames omitted`

**more info**:

- GridGain is run as an embedded, so I did not set GRIDGAIN_HOME.
- The jar is packaged using gradle 'spring-boot' plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since gridgain is embedded try setting the GRIDGAIN_HOME anyway. That should solve your problem.